# Retrieve text and tags from XML using java

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have an xml file as follows:

```
<extended>
   <p>text A</p>
   <p>text B</p>
   <p>text C</p>
</extended>
```

Using Java I would like to extract the text **and** the tags from the extended node. So my expected output would be:

```
<p>text A</p>
<p>text B</p>
<p>text C</p>
```

Here's my code so far:

```
String textString;
NodeList extendedNodeList = XYZ.getElementsByTagName("extended");
if(extendedNodeList !=null && extendedNodeList.getLength() == 1) {
    Node subChildNode = extendedNodeList.item(0);
    if(subChildNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
        textString = subChildNode.getTextContent();
}
```

However, this strips the tags, leaving me with:

```
text A
text B
text C
```

How to leave in the `<p>` tags? Any help would be greatly appreciated :).

A.

Comment: Try removing the innermost `if` condition !! just print textString

Comment: Not sure that helps.. even if I remove the conditional I'll still be left with a textString bereft of <p> tags.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem

```
NodeList extendedNodeList = XYZ.getElementsByTagName("extended");
if(extendedNodeList !=null && extendedNodeList.getLength() == 1) {
    Node extendedNode = extendedNodeList.item(0);
    if (extendedNode.hasChildNodes()) {
        NodeList childNodes = extendedNode.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < childNodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Node pNode = childNodes.item(i);
            if(pNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element element = (Element)pNode;
                System.out.println("<" + element.getTagName() + ">" + element.getTextContent() + "</" + element.getTagName() + ">");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however that brings in the <extended> tags but not the <p> tags.

Comment: And here I thought you could figure it out. Well, I've updated my post with a complete solution (untested).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I already know I can iterate through the children (and wrote the code for it).. I was just wondering if that step could be skipped but it looks not. Another way is to transform the xml into text but the number of lines of code to do that is above the extra lines required for the inner loop.